# What do I need to do on a server to make sure an initially bare Git repository updates the working directory there when I push to it?

Tags: git, remote-server

On the remote machine:

1. `mkdir mlcode.git && cd mlcode.git && git init --bare`
2. Create a `post-receive` file in `~/mlcode.git/hooks` containing

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/mlcode
   export GIT_WORK_TREE
   git checkout -f
   ```
3. `chmod +x ~/mlcode.git/hooks/post-receive`
4. `mkdir mlcode`

Then on the local machine I set up the remote machine as a repo and push. This appears to work (the remote repository is updated as expected, fetches confirm this, etc.). But nothing is checked out.

After some experimenting it appears that I need an additional step after (after first pushing?) on the server where I explicitly create the branch and check it out with something like

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/mlcode git checkout -f -B thebranch
```

Once that's done pushes update the contents of `mlcode` as expected. But I'm not sure the manual checkout and branch creation is either sufficient or necessary (it's absent from many online instructions I've found): It just seems to have worked.

What do I need to do on my server machine to make sure an initially bare repository updates the working directory there when I push to it? Is the explicit step above necessary? Would a different `post-receive` avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes: a different (better) post-receive could avoid this problem.  In particular, if you have exactly one work-tree that should be updated if and only if one particular branch `xyz` is updated, you can explicitly check out that one branch when that one branch is updated:

```
#! /bin/sh
while read ohash nhash ref; do
    case "$ref" in
    refs/heads/xyz) git --work-tree=/path/to/deploy checkout -f xyz;;
    esac
done
```

This is still not a *great* post-receive hook, but it's a slight improvement.  Read the discussion below for more.

#### Discussion

Try this exercise first: what happens in any *ordinary*, non-bare, Git repository when you run `git checkout` with no arguments, or `git checkout -f` with no branch name?  What branch gets checked out?  Feel free to look up the answer in [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).  Compare this to what branch gets checked out if you *do* give `git checkout` a branch name.

Similarly, run `git branch` in a non-bare repository.  Which branch is current?  How does Git even *know?*

Now that you have done that exercise, what branch do you suppose gets checked out in a *bare* repository?  (Seriously, do the exercise, it will help you remember the answer and explain all this.)

#### Push delivers commits and updates references

When a repository is the target of a `git push`, what really happens is that the receiving host system gets a series of objects (commits and/or tags, and/or trees and/or blobs that go with them) from some other Git.  Then, it gets one or more requests (regular push) or commands (force push) from that other Git: "please set `refs/tags/v1.2` to `1234567...`" or "set `refs/heads/branchname` to `feedbee...`, and I really mean it!"  It gets one such request-or-command per *refspec*, based on what whoever ran `git push` gave as arguments to `git push`.

If the reference names a branch (`refs/head/whatever`), and the branch update is accepted (is a proper fast-forward or is forced), this updates the corresponding branch in the repository's map of branch-names to commit-IDs.

#### A bare repository still has a current branch and index

As you have figured out by now, `git checkout` with no arguments (or with just `-f`) checks out the *current branch*.

The post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/path/to/work/tree checkout -f
```

is not *wrong*, precisely.  But it's quick and dirty, and kind of sloppy.  The receive received something—probably some commit(s), maybe a tag too or instead—and put them in the bare repository.  Did that *change* the hash ID stored under the *current* branch?  Who knows?  What *is* the current branch anyway?

That part, at least, is easy to answer.  The current branch is the one stored in `HEAD`.  Use `git symbolic-ref HEAD` to view it.  If this says `refs/heads/master`, the current branch is `master`.

Did we just get an update for that branch?  Who knows?  Well, the post-receive hook itself *could* know.  It is *supposed* to read all of standard input, which *tells it*, one line at a time, which references—branches, tags, or whatever—were updated, and what their old and new hash IDs are.  *This* post-receive hook doesn't bother.  It just re-checks-out the *current* branch, updated or not.

If the current branch *did* get updated, Git will know which files to replace (or add or delete) based on the *index*, which is keeping track of what Git wrote into the work-tree.  If the current branch did not get updated, Git does a bunch of busy-work and nothing really changes (this is the "glorified no-op" in the documentation).

This is true even in a bare repository.  Normally, there would be no work-tree at all, but the `--work-tree` or `$GIT_WORK_TREE` that you supply here overrides the `core.bare` setting for the duration of the `git checkout`.

But the branch that's checked out is the *current* branch.  It's still the current branch afterward, because there's no branch *name* in this `git checkout` command.

> ... where I explicitly ... check [a branch] out with something like
>
> ```
> GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/mlcode git checkout -f -B thebranch
> ```

When you check out with a branch name, you get that particular branch, *and* Git changes the *current* branch to the one you specified.  A future `git checkout` with *no* branch name will check out ... the *current* branch, i.e., the one you just specified here (assuming no intervening change).

#### The current branch of any repository also affects clones

When you `git clone` from some repository, bare or not, the new clone starts out with a current branch.  Most often, that's `master`—but this is just because most often, you clone an existing repository whose *current* branch is `master`.  The new clone starts out with the same current branch, by default.  (You can use `-b branch-or-tag-name` to change this behavior on the `clone` side.)

This means that whenever you change the current branch of a bare repository that's used for cloning as well as for pushing, you change which branch someone will get when they clone that repository.  That's probably no big deal, but you should be aware of it.

#### There's only one index

A bare repository normally has *no* work-tree.  As such, it doesn't really need an index either, since an index remembers what's in the work-tree and is used for building the *next* commit to make, neither of which has any meaning in this work-tree-less bare repository.

Once you start giving it a temporary work-tree with `git --work-tree=... checkout`, though, suddenly *the* (single) index matters.  That index is what keeps track of what's in the work-tree.  If you always give this bare repository the *same* work-tree every time, the fact that there's just the one index is not a problem: one work-tree, one index, everything matches.

But if you ever give it a *second, different* temporary work-tree ... well, now you have one index trying to keep track of two different work-trees.  This does not work that well.  Git is a bit clever, and *sometimes* notices that the index is all wrong for the work-trees and makes it all work out.  But it doesn't *always* work out.  You now need at least *two* index files for your two work-trees (or alternatively you can wipe out the index file *and* the work-tree each time, so that there's nothing out of sync, but this defeats the cache/speed aspect of an index that keeps track of the work-tree).

Comment: But then in sounds like I could just have `GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/mlcode git checkout -f -B thebranch` in my `post-receive` and that would do the trick. No?

Comment: `-B` means *create a new branch* (or reset it if it exists) (and then get on it). So, yes, but now we're back to "sloppy": we make Git do a lot of work when there's no work to be done and we could tell that by reading the list of references.

Comment: That comes from reading the references (bad day?). What's wrong with having Git do the work? That's what its there for. And it really doesn't sound like a lot of work anyway. What exactly is the unnecessary step preformed by `-B` (and is it costly)?

Comment: Nothing really *wrong* with it. It's a bit weird though. A new, empty repository is created on branch `master` (`HEAD` refers to `master`). The first time you push a `master` (so that `master` now exists), this creates your desired branch `thebranch` from whatever value `master` has, and only then does everything get deployed. After that, on every push, this re-creates the name at the current (possibly updated, possibly not) value of `thebranch`, then does a comparison of the index vs the work-tree, whether or not it must. It's the checkout itself that's somewhat expensive, more than the `-B`.

Comment: What I really want to do though is checkout whatever branch was just pushed. None of these approaches seem to do that. `git checkout -f` does that, but what's missing (it seems) is sorting out just what the current branch is (on the server). (Note that in this solution, no one is pulling, so perhaps I need a different solution entirely here. What I'm doing is *deploying* with Git, and perhaps there's a better way to accomplish that.)

Comment: [Another example](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#file-post-receive) (along the lines of your suggestion) also had codes the branch. Is there a simple way to not do that? Meanwhile, I find in many places (e.g., [here](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html), where several alternatives are discussed) that for cases where the branch is always the same, just `checkout -f` is recommended.

Comment: But none of these solutions seem other solutions seem to address the question here: [how to get the branch setup on the server so that something is actually checked out into a directory](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#gistcomment-2082196).

Comment: "checkout whatever branch was just pushed": then read the input, and see which branches, if any, were pushed. Choose a strategy to deal with *no* branches, or *two or more* branches, being pushed at a time (this is always possible). If branch `B` was pushed, run `git checkout B` but if branch `X` was pushed, run `git checkout X`. Note that the branch name is the result of taking `refs/heads/` off the reference name, i.e., `branch=${ref#refs/heads/}` in sh/bash.

Comment: And if I'm only interested in a specific branch, then your version will work because it specifies a branch as an argument to `checkout -f` [whereas the linked examples won't (without the initial setup I ask bout), correct](https://gist.github.com/noelboss/3fe13927025b89757f8fb12e9066f2fa#gistcomment-2107209)?

Comment: Right. And, the `-B` version works (albeit weirdly) because it creates a *new* branch the first time you invoke it, and then re-uses the current branch (whatever that is) to reset the branch every other time you invoke it. Should someone enter the bare repository and use `git branch` or `git symbolic-ref` to *change* the current branch, the `-B` version resets the argument branch to the current branch and then gets on the named `-B` branch. (This sort of highly context dependent behavior makes my teeth itch, as I like to put it.)